# Which think-tanks on economics do you use to keep up with the news?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, econometrics, reference-request

Whenever I have spare time, I like to go to [Bruegel](http://bruegel.org/) site and check their section on publications in macroeconomics. Here I usually find small publications of 20 something pages. The size is just about right. It's not as difficult as some papers, but it has as much content as one. For me it strikes the exact balance between a small article in the newspaper and a scientific paper.

I was wondering which think-tanks, or which other sources for this type of publications, do you use?  And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like also shorter columns, which are based on good academic papers. So, the [VOX](http://voxeu.org/), CEPR's policy portal is very good. They occasionally take unsolicited columns, but many are based on [CEPR](http://cepr.org/content/discussion-papers) or [NBER](http://www.nber.org/papers.html) working papers.

[Project Syndicate](https://www.project-syndicate.org/) publishes short and interesting op-ed economics articles.

Comment: I would add also: Peterson, Brookings, Center for American Progress, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The *Journal of Economic Perspectives* is really good. It tends to be less "news", however (but still worth checking out). If your looking for policy papers then you might check out the Peterson Institute. But, frankly, it sounds like your best bet may be **The Economist**. And if you're not up for shelling out any money for a subscription, then the podcast is great, too.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wanted the links for some of the references in the comments.

[Brookings Institute](https://www.brookings.edu/)

[Peterson Institute for International Economics](https://www.brookings.edu/)